# Cannot iterate through STL Set

Tags: c++, stl

There is something wrong with the way the loop in my program is configured. After doing a bit of debugging, I figured out that the loop is runs all the way up until the last iteration, right before temp is matched to target. `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)` is thrown and the program exits. (11)

```
bool isadjacent(string& a, string& b)
{
    int count = 0;
    int n = a.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] != b[i]) count++;
        if (count > 1) return false;
    }
    return count == 1 ? true : false;
}    


int shortestChainLen(string& start, string& target, set<string> &D)
{
    queue<QItem> Q;
    QItem item = {start, 1};
    Q.push(item);
    while (!Q.empty())
    {
        QItem curr = Q.front();
        Q.pop();
        for (set<string>::iterator it = D.begin(); it != D.end(); it++)
        {
            string temp = *it;
            if (isadjacent(curr.word, temp))
            {
                item.word = temp;
                item.len = curr.len + 1;
                Q.push(item);
                D.erase(temp);
                if (temp == target)
                    return item.len;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is what the XCode debugger found, but I am not exactly sure how to interpret it.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're erasing the element of the set that your iterator currently points at on the line

```
D.erase(temp);
```

when that happens, the iterator is invalidated and any further use of it is undefined behavior.  You want to instead structure your code as:

```
    for (set<string>::iterator it = D.begin(); it != D.end();) {
        if (isadjacent(curr.word, *it)) {
            item.word = *it;
            item.len = curr.len + 1;
            Q.push(item);
            it = D.erase(it);
            if (item.word == target)
                return item.len;
        } else {
            ++it;
        }
    }
```

using the `erase` method that takes an iterator and returns an iterator referring to the next item.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I have been working on this for hours and I can't believe I missed it.